# Is there a push notification API for Windows XP/Vista/Win7?

Tags: api, windows-7, push-notification, windows-xp, windows-vista

There is WNS for Windows 8, Urban AirShip for Android and iOS devices but I can't seem to find an API for push notifications on Windows XP, Vista, or Windows 7.

Is there an API for these OS's?

If not, why isn't there? Is there a reason or is it just that no one want to invest in "hacky" technology for "old" operating systems?

Comment: The answer to "why isn't there" is always the same: the benefit did not outweigh the cost.  Smartphones weren't a thing prior to Windows 8.

Comment: Also, I'm not necessarily just talking about built into Microsoft's OS's but also 3rd party APIs that I can pull into a desktop application and use.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any natively supported push APIs for these operating systems, no. As Robert Harvey said there in a comment, the benefit likely simply does not outweigh the cost. People using those operating systems probably aren't overly invested in the next wave of technology, so nobody bothers putting in push notifications, which weren't really relevant on most desktop machines until Windows 8 was already released anyway. As for why they won't retroactively add it as an update, that's easy: money. If people want the new and exciting technologies of tomorrow, with push notifications and all, they have to buy Windows 8. Microsoft gains nothing by adding features like that into old operating systems.

But since I imagine you're asking this *for a reason*, I'm sure you could write a Windows Service with--ha--"relative ease" that would accept notifications (even, if you're feeling techy, through SignalR) and relay them out through the notification bar on those operating systems.

That could actually be a pretty cool piece of open source software to put out there: something that lets you set up push channels easily on those operating systems that will almost definitely never receive support from Microsoft for such behaviors.

Comment: It is for the reason of sending push notifications to desktop applications where users still have an older Operating System. Many people still have Windows 7 especially and if I want to engage with them via push notifications it's not as simple as pulling in an API and making a few calls like it is for Windows 8, or mobile devices.

Comment: @BrianTHannan Oh, no, I completely understand why you'd want to do it. That's why I gave my suggestion of how you could. What I mean with those first paragraph is just why it won't be done by Microsoft.